# How to get a customer's ID from a webhook with Braintree?

Tags: node.js, braintree

How can I get a customer's ID from a webhook notification from Braintree?

For example, I can do the following to get their ID:

```
gateway.webhookNotification.parse(sampleNotification.bt_signature, sampleNotification.bt_payload, (err, webhookNotification) => {
     let customerId = webhookNotification.subject.subscription.transactions[0].customer.id;
});
```

But this requires the user to have at least one transaction first. How can I get a customer's ID if they do not have any transactions yet (eg. a new user)?

Here is the response when logging `webhookNotification`:

```
WebhookNotification {
   timestamp: '2017-04-30T11:01:33Z',
   kind: 'subscription_charged_unsuccessfully',
   subject: { 
      subscription: { 
         id: 'jywgnr', 
         transactions: [], 
         addOns: [], 
         discounts: [] 
       }
   },
   subscription: Subscription { 
      id: 'jywgnr', 
      transactions: [], 
      addOns: [], 
      discounts: [] 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the subscription webhook.  That appears to return a [payment method token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/node#payment_method_token) in the payload, which you can use in [paymentMethod.find()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/find/node) call.

From that paymentMethod.find('token') result object, you can retrieve the customer_id.

EDIT: Looks like because the subscription was unsuccessful, there is no payment method token in that webhook.  There is, though, a subscription ID, which you can use in a [Subscription.find()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/find/) API call, which will certainly return a result object that contains a payment method token.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not return a payment method token. I logged the full response. I've added it to my question.

Comment: What if you took the subscription ID, inserted it into a Braintree.Subscription.Find('jywgnr')? The result object of that will include a payment method token.  Made that change in my original answer!

Comment: Yep, managed to get the customer's ID from first running `subscription.find(webhookNotification.subscription.id)` and then `paymentMethod.find(subscription.paymentMethodToken)` which returns a `paymentMethod` object that contains a customer's ID. Thanks!